# node request library return an error on api call

Tags: node.js, request, bit.ly

I'm using Bitly api to shorten links:
http://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_shorten
But then in the console log im getting an Error...

```
var Bitly = require('bitly');


  var bitly = new Bitly('key');

module.exports = function(req, res) {
  var term = req.query.text;
  handleSearchString(term, req, res);
};


function handleSearchString(term, req, res) {

  var response;
  try {

    response = sync.await(request({
      url: 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/link/shorten',
      qs: {
        //link: term,
        'access_token': key,
        'longUrl': term,
      },

      timeout: 15 * 1000
    }, sync.defer()));
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send('\nError!\n');
    return;
  }
            var html = '<p> ' + response + '  </p>';
            res.json([{
             body: html
      }]);

};
```

Console.log outputs Error!,

Comment: Have you tried using the Bitly Api? [link] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-bitlyapi)

Comment: just added it now. changed the code. getting erros